Corrupt zpool disks not being discovered. How do I rebuild?
I have a Proxmox server with a few zpools. One of the zpools rust01 is a 4-disk zpool, where the metadata and write cache were some nvme m.2 drives on the motherboard (one for each - I know, stupid, but that's what was done).
It appears as though the rust01 has had a catastrophic failure.
When I click on rust01 in the Server View, I get the following error:
could not activate storage 'rust01', zfs error: cannot import 'rust01': I/O error (500)

When I go to { Server } > Disks > ZFS, I do not see the rust01 zpool.

When I go to { Server } > Disks I don't even see the 4-disks or the special metadata  -file or the read/write cache drives.

When I run zpool status -x I get all pools are healthy

When I run zpool import rust01 I get the following message:
cannot import 'rust01': I/O error
Destroy and re-create the pool from
a backup source.



When I run zpool status rust01 I get cannot open 'rust01': no such pool,
When I reboot the server, below is the error emailed to me:
ZFS has detected that a device was removed.
impact: Fault tolerance of the pool may be compromised.
eid: 10
class: statechange
state: UNAVAIL
host: pve01
time: 2024-09-14 21:20:32-0500
vpath: /dev/nvme2n1p1
vphys: pci-0000:41:00.0-nvme-1
vguid: 0x297D516B1F1D6494
devid: nvme-Samsung_SSD_970_EVO_Plus_2TB_S6S2NS0T815592K-part1
pool: rust01 (0xE4AAC2680D8B6A7E)

When I run zpool destroy rust01 I get the following error cannot open 'rust01': no such pool.
Ideally, I would like to get rust01 back online. I am fairly certain the issue is the special metadata disk mentioned in the email above. That said, I would be happy to destroy and recreate rust01. All of the VMs on that disk are backed up, so I can easily restore if needed. My problem, however, is that I can't find a way to get Proxmox/ZFS to release the disks associated with the corrupt rust01 zpool. Below is the output of lsblk:
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    1 465.8G  0 disk 
|-sda1        8:1    1  1007K  0 part 
|-sda2        8:2    1     1G  0 part 
`-sda3        8:3    1   464G  0 part 
sdb           8:16   1 465.8G  0 disk 
|-sdb1        8:17   1  1007K  0 part 
|-sdb2        8:18   1     1G  0 part 
`-sdb3        8:19   1   464G  0 part 
sdc           8:32   1   3.6T  0 disk 
|-sdc1        8:33   1   3.6T  0 part 
`-sdc9        8:41   1     8M  0 part 
sdd           8:48   1   3.6T  0 disk 
|-sdd1        8:49   1   3.6T  0 part 
`-sdd9        8:57   1     8M  0 part 
sde           8:64   1   3.6T  0 disk 
|-sde1        8:65   1   3.6T  0 part 
`-sde9        8:73   1     8M  0 part 
sdf           8:80   1   3.6T  0 disk 
|-sdf1        8:81   1   3.6T  0 part 
`-sdf9        8:89   1     8M  0 part 
sdg           8:96   1     0B  0 disk 
sdh           8:112  1     0B  0 disk 
sdi           8:128  1     0B  0 disk 
sdj           8:144  1     0B  0 disk 
sdk           8:160  1     0B  0 disk 
sdl           8:176  1     0B  0 disk 
sdm           8:192  1     0B  0 disk 
sdn           8:208  1     0B  0 disk 
sr0          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
sr1          11:1    1  1024M  0 rom  
sr2          11:2    1  1024M  0 rom  
sr3          11:3    1  1024M  0 rom  
zd0         230:0    0     4M  0 disk 
zd16        230:16   0    80G  0 disk 
`-zd16p1    230:17   0    80G  0 part 
zd32        230:32   0    64G  0 disk 
|-zd32p1    230:33   0     1M  0 part 
|-zd32p2    230:34   0     2G  0 part 
`-zd32p3    230:35   0    62G  0 part 
zd48        230:48   0    40G  0 disk 
|-zd48p1    230:49   0   600M  0 part 
|-zd48p2    230:50   0     1G  0 part 
`-zd48p3    230:51   0  38.4G  0 part 
zd64        230:64   0    32G  0 disk 
|-zd64p1    230:65   0    31G  0 part 
|-zd64p2    230:66   0     1K  0 part 
`-zd64p5    230:69   0   975M  0 part 
zd80        230:80   0    90G  0 disk 
|-zd80p1    230:81   0   100M  0 part 
|-zd80p2    230:82   0    16M  0 part 
|-zd80p3    230:83   0  89.4G  0 part 
`-zd80p4    230:84   0   523M  0 part 
zd96        230:96   0    90G  0 disk 
|-zd96p1    230:97   0   499M  0 part 
|-zd96p2    230:98   0   128M  0 part 
|-zd96p3    230:99   0  88.5G  0 part 
`-zd96p4    230:100  0   920M  0 part 
zd112       230:112  0   100G  0 disk 
|-zd112p1   230:113  0   499M  0 part 
|-zd112p2   230:114  0    99M  0 part 
|-zd112p3   230:115  0    16M  0 part 
`-zd112p4   230:116  0  99.4G  0 part 
zd128       230:128  0    64G  0 disk 
|-zd128p1   230:129  0     1M  0 part 
|-zd128p2   230:130  0     2G  0 part 
`-zd128p3   230:131  0    62G  0 part 
zd144       230:144  0    90G  0 disk 
|-zd144p1   230:145  0   500M  0 part 
`-zd144p2   230:146  0  89.5G  0 part 
zd160       230:160  0    60G  0 disk 
|-zd160p1   230:161  0   100M  0 part 
|-zd160p2   230:162  0    16M  0 part 
|-zd160p3   230:163  0  59.4G  0 part 
`-zd160p4   230:164  0   450M  0 part 
zd176       230:176  0    32G  0 disk 
|-zd176p1   230:177  0     1M  0 part 
|-zd176p2   230:178  0     2G  0 part 
`-zd176p3   230:179  0    30G  0 part 
zd192       230:192  0   100G  0 disk 
|-zd192p1   230:193  0   450M  0 part 
|-zd192p2   230:194  0    99M  0 part 
|-zd192p3   230:195  0  15.8M  0 part 
|-zd192p4   230:196  0  89.4G  0 part 
`-zd192p5   230:197  0   256K  0 part 
zd208       230:208  0    32G  0 disk 
|-zd208p1   230:209  0   600M  0 part 
|-zd208p2   230:210  0     1G  0 part 
`-zd208p3   230:211  0  30.4G  0 part 
zd224       230:224  0     1M  0 disk 
nvme1n1     259:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
|-nvme1n1p1 259:1    0   1.8T  0 part 
`-nvme1n1p9 259:2    0     8M  0 part 
nvme3n1     259:3    0   1.8T  0 disk 
|-nvme3n1p1 259:4    0   1.8T  0 part 
`-nvme3n1p9 259:5    0     8M  0 part 
nvme0n1     259:6    0   1.8T  0 disk 
|-nvme0n1p1 259:7    0   1.8T  0 part 
`-nvme0n1p9 259:8    0     8M  0 part 
nvme2n1     259:9    0   1.8T  0 disk 
|-nvme2n1p1 259:10   0   1.8T  0 part 
`-nvme2n1p9 259:11   0     8M  0 part 

There are other VMs on this host running on other zpools, that appear fine. As such, reinstalling everything is not an option I want to entertain.
UPDATE: After running through the steps outlined in Fix your dead SSD with the power cycle method the 4TB hard drives are showing up in Proxmox, albeit the zpool is not accessible. Some progress, but still no access to the data.
Any ideas on how to proceed other than a wiping the disks in the affected zpool?

It would be nice to see lsblk output as well.

Hi @drookie. I've added the output as requested. Thank you for offering your help.

In the end I gave up and decided to destroy zpool rust01.
When trying to destroying a corrupt zpool used in Proxmox, you may run into problems where the disk seems always engaged and command line and UI attempts to wipe the disk(s) fail. You may need to comment out the zpool in /etc/pve/storage.cfg. After that, you will be able to wipe all of the disks associate with your failed zpool. Click here for more information.
